# Regular expression with whitelisted characters and blacklisted keywords (Google forms)

Tags: regex, google-forms, regular-language

I am trying to create a Google form that accepts long answers regex data validation.

I need following conditions in my RegEx:

**Whitelisted characters :** Alphanumeric, white space, new line, and set of allowed special characters

**Blacklisted keywords :** wordA, wordB, wordC

**Length limit :** less than 500 characters

So I came up with my RegEx design as below :

```
([^a-zA-Z0-9\.\(\)\%\:\s\n\~\/]+|wordA|wordB|wordC)|^[\S\s]{500,}$
```

If there is any match in response, I wanted Google forms to reject the input.

With the Regex setting set to "Doesn't contain", above RegEx worked fine **except for the new line** part.

It seems that Google form's regular expression does not accept: **Doesn't contain** `[^\n]`.

For example, Doesn't contain `[^a]` will only allows alphabet 'a' as valid input (which works as well). But if I do the same for `[^\n]`, it won't work. (input will only accept 'a', but line break will throw out error).

[image]

However, if i change the Regex setting to "Contains(or matches)" instead of "Doesn't contain", both `a` and `\n` works (Input will accept only 'a' or line breaks).

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: `{500,}` this is 500 or more, this `{0,500}` is less than 500 characters.

Comment: Yup that's why it will be a match when anything exceed 500 characters. In my current regex i am allowing input that has 0 match. My problem is, all the other symbols I whitelisted are accepted except for the linebreak.